# Apple ID disabled and unlock email sent to strange address

Tags: icloud, apple-id

My iPad Pro was locked during New Year’s Eve. I've tried to change the password but my Apple ID is disabled. I went to the website to change my password and filled the requested information. An email was sent to my email but I don’t recognize that email — I don't even know an email server that starts with ‘@m’. When I was setting up the iPad it didn't ask me for an email. I was surprised because on my iPhone I had to use my Gmail.

[image]

My Apple ID is disabled. The only way to enable it is to reset my password. A link wasn’t sent to my email that I used to set the iPad up, but I didn’t use any email I use iCloud mail.

[image]

Comment: What exactly has been ‘locked’? What do you mean your Apple ID is ‘disabled’? I've edited your question title to better summarise the problem, feel free to [edit] with further details.

Comment: Isn’t it your j***@mac.com email - which is your iCloud/Apple ID ?? your gmail is only an alternative email

Comment: Thanks for your help , deeply appreciated.Thanks for editing it to ,

Comment: The only email adress that use was j*****@icloud.com

Comment: Are you suggesting that someone has broken into your Apple ID and changed the email address?

Comment: Apple seems to let people register any e-mail address and never check that it's the correct one:https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/346719/112208