# How to unlock an Apple ID through e-mail?

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id, accounts, authentication

My AppleID was just registered and used on iCloud -- but not by myself.  Perhaps a Christmas present erroneously associated with my e-mail, or maybe not.  Could be malicious.  Either way I want to secure the account which has been hijacked.

As it's a web-app, I asked on webapps:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123423/24327

then found I was able to gain control of a "fake" type, spam-trap, account:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123424/24327

So I also asked on the apple forum:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250043907

Not looking to spam the internet, but this is annoying and moderately concerning.  So, asking apple experts here:

How do I gain access to the account associated with my e-mail not having knowledge of the associated phone number?  Because I'm not able to proceed past that point.

Comment: *Your* Apple ID?  If it's yours, how/when did you register for it?

Comment: Exactly.  I never did register it.  Yet it uses my e-mail account.  If it uses my e-mail account, and Apple is sending me e-mails about it, then it must be my account.  Right....?

Comment: My "thufirh" account on the Apple forums is a different e-mail.

Comment: Then it's not *your* account.  You can't change an account for which you didn't register and don't have any of the credentials for.  It's entirely possible that someone mistyped an email address.

Comment: Maybe.  How would I know?  Either way, should be able to de-activate, gain, control, seperate the two accounts, something.  If Apple is sending me e-mails about the the account...

Comment: I would say speaking with an Apple customer services person might be the trick here...

Comment: You think you should be able to deactivate or gain control of *someone else's* account?  That kinda goes against pretty much goes against every security practice. Ever.

Comment: It could be for nefarious purposes.  If I go to login to the apple website and it asks my e-mail address, and I enter my e-mail address, then I'm logging into my account.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend contacting Apple through [this form.](https://www.apple.com/emea/support/itunes/contact.html) Or try using [Apple Support live chat.](https://getsupport.apple.com)

Comment: there's no chat option for me.  Why?  Because I can't answer the secret questions.